# AzureAD C# Desktop App - Outlook Extension

Tags: c#, outlook, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a .net class which consumes rest service endpoints of a third party system. The Third party system can be configured with different authentication principles, ranging from AzureAD/OpenIDConnect/ADFS. Depending on the Environment configuration depends on what the re-irect URI is on logging in. My specific scenario is AzureAD which I'm struggling with.

My application is an Outlook VTSO which doesnt have a the framework to facilitate a callback URL.

I'm unable to set up a localhost:3000 and monitor for traffic as that would require elevated rights that I dont have. I cant set a custom application handler in the registry and call my app because its not a standard desktop app.

I've tried using the following:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{###########APP_ID###############}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={################CLIENT_ID#################}&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient&response_type=code&scope=openid](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B###########APP_ID###############%7D/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%7B################CLIENT_ID#################%7D&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient&response_type=code&scope=openid)

But the resulting page isnt what I'd expect - Its blank with a querystring value in the URL for &code={looks like Base64 encoded string, but it isnt.} and &session_state={GUID}.

Previously when I've done this there has always been a custom redirect URI to finish at a page which says something like "You can close this page now" whilst having the Access Token & Refresh Token embedded in the HTML markup within the page/URL.

I'm sure other people must handle this with AzureAD authentication and I must be missing something.

Ideally I dont want to start my own Webview and scrape the details {I'm not even sure this is possible} but I'm failing to see how else I can authenticate a desktop VTSO extension.

The AzureAD tennant I'm authenticating against also uses Multi Factor Authentication so I need to get the user to authenticate the token and then use the refresh token to maintain an access token.

Note: I have control over the AzureAD Enterprise Application to add more endpoints & control over the third party app callback URI's (this is a requirement of oAuth to ensure the token came from the requesting app)

Comment: If you want to get access token and id token from `/authorize` endpoint directly, you should use Implicit grant flow instead of auth code flow. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-10-with-implicit-flow and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Comment: Keep in mind though you won't be able to obtain a refresh token with implicit grant flow -it's only available with auth-code / msal.js 2x.

Comment: So I should be using MSAL instead? it seems like everything is geared towards web applications which are geared to receve the response, i dont have that.

Comment: Microsoft recommends using [MSAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) written by protocol domain experts who follow a Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) methodology.